# Временное добавление Label в HBox javafx

Tags: javafx

При выборе CheckBox в значении true, в HBox должна временно появиться надпись. Пробовал сделать так, но если закомментировать последнюю очистку HBox, то будет видно, что Label добавляется после того как таймер отработает. Не пойму почему так? Может кто подскажет как правильно сделать

```
checkBox.selectedProperty()
            .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        hbox.getChildren().clear(); 
        hbox.getChildren().add(label);

        sleep(5000);

        hbox.getChildren().clear();
    } 
});

private void sleep(long millis) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(millis);
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Попробовал так:

```
 checkBox.selectedProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     if (newValue) {
         hbox.getChildren().clear(); 
         hbox.getChildren().add(label);

         sleep(5000);

     } 
 });

 private void sleep(long millis) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {
            thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        hbox.getChildren().clear();
    });

 }
```

Но:
1) Данное событие почему-то срабатывает только один раз;
2) При повторном выборе CheckBox во время работы события, оно должно перезапускаться.

Comment: нельзя усыплять UI поток. тем самым вы блокирует обработку любых событий. запускайте отдельный поток и в нем используйте `Platform.runLater`, чтобы обновить UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь для этого [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html).

Примерный код :

```
Service < Void > service = new Service < Void > () {
@Override
protected Task < Void > createTask() {
    return new Task < Void > () {@
        Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            hbox.getChildren().clear();
            hbox.getChildren().add(label);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
        }
    };
}};
service.setOnSucceeded(event - > {
    box.getChildren().remove(label);
});
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) - > {
    if (newValue) {
        service.restart()
    }
});
```

Comment: В прицепе работает, пришлось только                
            hbox.getChildren().clear();
            hbox.getChildren().add(label);                                                                                обернуть в Platform.runLater